# « Alors là » et « Je vois pas » : des synonymes pour « Je ne sais pas » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Est-ce que c’est vrai que « alors là » et « je vois pas » s’utilisent comme une façon de dire « je ne sais pas » ? Je les ai vus tous les deux et c’est l’impression que ça me donne mais j’en suis pas sûr !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, mais plutôt dans le langage parlé. "Alors là" est généralement utilisé pour renforcer l’idée de ne pas savoir:

> C'est quoi le théorème de Pythagore? Alors là, j'en sais rien du tout....

On peut aussi l'utiliser tout seul, auquel cas le fait de ne pas savoir est implicite:

> C'est quoi le théorème de Pythagore? Alors là....

Pour ce qui est de "je ne vois pas", c'est un peu pareil:

> Tu fais comment pour résoudre cette équation? Je [ne] vois pas...

ou même pour renforcer l’idée de ne pas savoir:

> Tu fais comment pour résoudre cette équation? Je [ne] vois pas du tout...

Comment: Super, ça a bien du sens ! Merci beaucoup 

Answer (score 0):

Oui, « alors là »  s'utilise bien pour dire « je ne sais pas », mais ce n'est pas la seule signification de cette locution.

**I** Elle s'utilise pour dire « je ne sais pas » mais lorsque utilisée ainsi elle n'est pas suivie de « je ne sais pas » ; cela arrive cependant, ce qui confirme que la locution n'est pas strictement équivalente à « je ne sais pas » mais plus généralement sert à donner  une idée d'incapacité ou à renforcer une assertion à l'effet de dire strictement que quelque chose n'est pas possible ou qu'on ne sait pas.

— Vous savez s'il y a un dernier train pour la banlieue ?
— Alors là … Vous m'en demandez trop …

« Alors là » s'utilise aussi

(1) pour exprimer qu'une situation a une conséquence automatique ou inévitable,
(2) simplement pour introduire la suite à une situation,
(3) pour indiquer un moment très proche du moment où la personne parle,
(4) pour indiquer un moment donné dans le passé ou le futur,
(5) pour indiquer ce qui se fait habituellement dans une situation particulière, qui peut se réaliser n'importe quand,
(6) en renforcement de l'idée de l'incapacité  à fournir une aide ou un renseignement ou à faire quelque chose.

1. — Je viens d'apprendre la nouvelle  que des renards rodaient autour des poulaillers.
   — Alors là il va falloir se dépêcher et renforcer les attaches des grillages.
2. — Nous n'avons plus de papier pour la machine, les livraisons sont arrêtées ;
   — alors là changeons de fournisseur.
3. — J'ai beaucoup de choses à voir en ville aujourd'hui ; alors là nous allons partir et je ne peux pas m'occuper de votre cas.
4. (a) Les sirènes avaient commencé à hurler ; alors là il a pris peur et s'est réfugié dans une grange, ou c'est ce qu'il croyait faire tout au moins.
   (b) Vous verrez la lumière devenir pâle ; alors là n'attendez pas et enfoncez ce bouton.
5. Il arrive parfois que ce pont commence à être mouillé par les vagues ; alors là ils n'attendent pas et l'interdisent tout de suite aux passagers.
6. (a)
   — Tu penses qu'en choisissant cet itinéraire on a plus de chance d'arriver avant eux ?
   — Alors là … Je ne sais pas, il faudrait demander à Pierre.
   (b)
   — Tu pourrais m'aider à faire ce dessin ?
   — Alors là, le dessin n'est pas mon fort, Je ne ferais rien de bon.

**II** "Je ne vois pas" s'utilise aussi pour dire simplement qu'une chose n'est pas visible  (ou des chose, évidemment) bien que plus couramment on utilise un pronom supplémentaire.

- Je (ne) le/la/les vois pas.